# How to raise a zero-one matrix to any power in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix, zero

I made a zero-one matrix with power 2. However, I want the code to be applied to any power the user enters. I tried several times, but it didn't work.

Here's a part of the code that would concern you.

Notes: Suppose the user has entered his (n*m) matrix which is "a", as n and m are equals and they are denoted by s.

```
k=0;
for(int j=0; j<s; j++)
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
    {
        m[k]=0;

        for(int t=0; t<s; t++)
        m[k]+=a[j][t]*a[t][i];

        k++;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my implementation for matrix exponentiation:

```
struct matrix {
    intt m[K][K];
    matrix() {
        memset (m, 0, sizeof (m));
    }
    matrix operator * (matrix b) {
        matrix c = matrix();
        for (intt i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            for (intt k = 0; k < K; k++) {
                for (intt j = 0; j < K; j++) {
                    c.m[i][j] = (c.m[i][j] + m[i][k] * b.m[k][j]) % MOD;
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
    matrix pow (intt n) {
        if (n <= 0) {
            return matrix();
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            return *this;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            return (*this) * pow (n - 1);
        } else {
            matrix X = pow (n / 2);
            return X * X;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It appears to be more complex than I thought, that I need some time to analyze it before trying it. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm assuming `K` and `MOD` are constants and `intt` is an alias defined elsewhere.  Recommend adding some explanation of your method because at the moment you've got a code-only answer, and those are only truly useful to [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) unless the code is blisteringly simple or self-documenting (which this isn't).

Comment: `matrix operator * (matrix b)` should most likely be `matrix operator * (const matrix& b)`, so you won't make an un-necessary copy.

Comment: @vsoftco I'd also avoid returning a matrix by copy both in the multiplication and in the pow recursion. If there were the possibility of move semantics, things would be different, but as it is the number of copies would explode.

Comment: @BarishNamazov The idea of doing the even case by splitting in two the power is very nice.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana That's the "square-and-multiply" algorithm, it's very useful as it computes the power in O(log n) steps, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring And yes you're right, the code can definitely be further optimized.

Comment: @vsoftco Thank you for the link. I totally ignored both the strategy and its name. Even if I used something similar by factorizing higher powers reusing  lower ones. This is definitely smarter.

Comment: @user4581301 for convenience, intt is defined long long and you can set K to any integer you want, K will be size of matrix. I don't think one who reads my code will not understand what does intt mean, or K. Anyway, in post put his code for multiplication it means s/he knows what is matrix, and the power function uses well known squaring exponentiation, which can is easy to understand.
Thanks.

Comment: "the power function uses well known squaring exponentiation" Add this to the answer, because in order to make this leap from the code, the reader must already know Square and Multiply. If they already knew, they likely would not have asked this question.